# multiple asynchronous AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am doing a AJAX call to check the progress of a stored procedure execution. The stored procedure logs progress percentage in an additional table. I call using AJAX the page which executes the stored procedure and with another AJAX call another page which queries that additional table and returns the status value.

The problem I’m encountering is that it looks like all responses come at the same time, at the response of the longest AJAX request. Please see the picture below:

[image]

The second request should be processed before the first one as it takes only few milliseconds to respond.

The above result is accomplished by the jQuery code listed below:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.post('BS_process.asp',{u:<%=UniqID%>, p:<%=ProfileID%>}).done(function(response){
//          DO STUFF
        }).fail(function(){
//          DO STUFF
        });

        $.post('BS_progress_ajax.asp',{u:<%=UniqID%>}).done(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });     
    });
```

Now I’m not too sure, but I think it is happening because of server limitation of simultaneous requests. My requirement is to get each response immediately.  Eventually I will implement an interval to check the progress.

Please advise me how to go about this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because session is single threaded per session. Requests to ASP scripts for the same session can only be processed sequentially so only one request will be handled at a time. To stop this you will need to stop using session on the page and turn it off: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244465/en-us. If you need session you may need to instead use a database.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about the database solution?

Comment: You would first generate a token after a user logs in and then store data using the token as a key in the database. You would need to have expiry and cleanup. It's quite an involved process and you would need to be mindful of security. With asp.net you can use readonly for pages that you want to handle multiple requests that don't update session.

Comment: the readonly asp.net seems to be sufficient. Will have a try.

Comment: Have manage to implement the asp.net readonly solution and works well. Thank you.